# Unknown arduino syntax

Tags: arduino

Just found this in a code example:

```
Serial.println(mpu.testConnection() ? 
    F("MPU6050 connection successful") :
    F("MPU6050 connection failed")
);
```

I understand the ? and : syntax but what is the `F` actually meaning?

Comment: F is a trace/log function ? maybe a #define somewhere ?

Comment: Please see [mcve]. Also, one of the most important skills you need to learn is how to search. This question is a failure of that skill.

Answer (score 4):

From *[here](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/Printf)*:

the F() macro puts printf() *(and Serial.println)* formatting strings into flash.
Example:

```
Serial.printf(F("Hello World\n"));
Serial.printf(F("Value is:%3d\n"), value);
```

Link also provides code snippet examples of test for existence of *F()* macro before using them in your code.